# Acralyzer dashboard on cloudant returns error 503

Tags: cloudant

I have set up acralyzer using cloudant based on [this blog](http://www.toptal.com/android/automated-android-crash-reports-with-acra-and-cloudant), but when I try to access my ACRA dashboard, cloudant returns error 503, "No server is available to handle this request"

My storage database name is "acra-raestloz_test_database", my acralyzer database name is "acra-raestloz_test_databaseacralyzer". According to the blog, my dashboard would be https://raestloz_test_database.cloudant.com/acralyzer/_design/acralyzer/index.html, but I only get error 503

Is there anything that I missed?

By the way, the database managed to accept crash report data sent from my Android emulator, I just can't access the dashboard

Comment: There are a couple of possibilities here so I'd suggest getting in touch with the Cloudant support team (support@cloudant.com or raise a ticket through the Cloudant UI) so we can look into it further.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to complete the previous answer as gives a hint but could be confusing.

First thing to take into account is that you need to create 2 database in Couldant, no only one. (just follow correctly the instructions that I didn't do...: https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/setup)

Once both databases are created in line with the constrains (acra-myapp as name and acralyzer the second one), you can use the acralyzer following the previous link BUT the dbname shall be "acralyzer", so you need to look for:

https://{accountname}.cloudant.com/acralyzer/_design/acralyzer/index.html

If you include in dbname your database name is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudant support told me that to access acralyzer dashboard, I have to use https://{accountname}.cloudant.com/{dbname}/_design/acralyzer/index.html and it works

Comment: hi @Raestloz ... hi tried this solution but i am getting {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}